# How to grab items from a DB by date

Tags: php, date, datetime, where-clause

This is my script:

```
$spending_period = time() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
$spending_period = date('Y-m-d', $spending_period);
$monthly_income_query="SELECT amount FROM budget_items WHERE (date_code >= '$spending_period') && (type=='Income') ORDER BY date_code DESC";
$monthly_income_result=mysql_query($monthly_income_query);
while($monthly_income_scan=mysql_fetch_array($monthly_income_result)){
    if($montly_income_counter >=1){
        $monthly_income=$monthly_income + $monthly_income_scan['amount'];
        }
    }
```

I receive an error that mysql_fetch_array() is not a valid result resource.

The goal is to grab only items in the budget_items table that have a date_code (using the DATE type) occurring within the last 30 days.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Um. How about some sample data in your database?

Comment: You should actually make a query that *works* in your database then convert it to code, can you post the full query that is generated?

Comment: Why bother doing the date logic in PHP when you can do it in the query using DATE_ADD and NOW?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to PHP/SQL. My first project is a tracker for my spending habits. Not sure how to use DATE_ADD and NOW. I got this to work:

$spending_period = time() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
$spending_period = date('Y-m-d', $spending_period);

$monthly_income_query="SELECT amount FROM budget_items WHERE (date_code >= '$spending_period') && (type='Income') ORDER BY date_code DESC";
$monthly_income_result=mysql_query($monthly_income_query);
while($monthly_income_scan=mysql_fetch_array($monthly_income_result)){
 $monthly_income=$monthly_income + $monthly_income_scan['amount'];
 }

Answer (score 0):

- If something doesn't work with your
  query - you may want to try it out in
  mysql console with some sample date.
- If data is returned, then try printing out a query. I have a hunch that `$spending_period` variable might not be interpolated correctly into your query string (try using `'{$spending_period}'` instead of `'$spending_period'`.

Comment: Is (date_code >= '$spending_period') prone to SQL injection? This will put the string directly into the query without proper encoding and {$spending_period} will encode correctly?

Comment: $spending_period is set in the code it self (i.e. no user input is used), thus it's not prone to SQL injection, unless time() function is hacked from php sources before compiling the php itself ,)

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the date as a strong and use CAST inside the select statement to accept the value as a date value.